# How to display content of Stacklayout children instead of name of the objects?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a StackLayout dynamically from code. Referring to the documentation and few of the questions on StackOverflow, this is what I have so far,

XAML View:

```
 <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items.Children}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public StackLayout Items { get; } = new StackLayout { 
        Margin = new Thickness(20),
        Children =
        {
            new Label { Text = "Primary colors" },
            new BoxView { Color = Color.Red },
            new BoxView { Color = Color.Yellow },
            new BoxView { Color = Color.Blue },
            new Label { Text = "Secondary colors" },
            new BoxView { Color = Color.Green },
            new BoxView { Color = Color.Orange },
            new BoxView { Color = Color.Purple }
        }
    };
```

The code in the VM is just an example, I would be having various objects in there. But right now, this is what I get as the result.

[image]

How do I show the actual content such as the Text, color of the labels and boxviews?

Comment: if you're going to manually construct the StackLayout like that there is really no point in using a BindableLayout

Comment: Then how do I get the Stacklayout to display on the view?

Comment: `page.Content = Items;`

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need add the the StackLayout which you create dynamically to the Page `Content`.

For example:

```
public partial class YourPage: ContentPage
{

   public YourPage()
    {
        YourVM vm = new YourVM();
        Content = vm.Items;
    }

}
```

your **ViewModel**:

```
public class YourVM
{
    public StackLayout Items { get; } = new StackLayout { 
    Margin = new Thickness(20),
    Children =
    {
        new Label { Text = "Primary colors" },
        new BoxView { Color = Color.Red },
        new BoxView { Color = Color.Yellow },
        new BoxView { Color = Color.Blue },
        new Label { Text = "Secondary colors" },
        new BoxView { Color = Color.Green },
        new BoxView { Color = Color.Orange },
        new BoxView { Color = Color.Purple }
    }
};
}
```